# TabBarController Transitions getting blank screen issue in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

In my application implemented TabBarController Transitions using reference code by Apple [Objective-C link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CustomTransitions/Listings/CustomTransitions_Slide_AAPLSlideTransitionAnimator_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015158-CustomTransitions_Slide_AAPLSlideTransitionAnimator_m-DontLinkElementID_34) And [Swift link](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/CustomTransitions-Swift). But when switch fast between two tabs some times I am getting blank screen, I tried many answers in Stack Overflow but no luck.

Please check below code for reference while doing TabBarController Transitions using Swift

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from)!
    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)!

    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
    let fromView: UIView
    let toView: UIView

    // In iOS 8, the viewForKey: method was introduced to get views that the
    // animator manipulates.  This method should be preferred over accessing
    // the view of the fromViewController/toViewController directly.
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from)!
        toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to)!
    } else {
        fromView = fromViewController.view
        toView = toViewController.view
    }

    let fromFrame = transitionContext.initialFrame(for: fromViewController)
    let toFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)

    // Based on the configured targetEdge, derive a normalized vector that will
    // be used to offset the frame of the view controllers.
    var offset: CGVector
    if self.targetEdge == UIRectEdge.left {
        offset = CGVector(dx: -1.0, dy: 0.0)
    } else if self.targetEdge == .right {
        offset = CGVector(dx: 1.0, dy: 0.0)
    } else {
        fatalError("targetEdge must be one of UIRectEdgeLeft, or UIRectEdgeRight.")
    }

    // The toView starts off-screen and slides in as the fromView slides out.
    fromView.frame = fromFrame
    toView.frame = toFrame.offsetBy(dx: toFrame.size.width * offset.dx * -1,
        dy: toFrame.size.height * offset.dy * -1)

    // We are responsible for adding the incoming view to the containerView.
    containerView.addSubview(toView)

    let transitionDuration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration, animations: {
        fromView.frame = fromFrame.offsetBy(dx: fromFrame.size.width * offset.dx,
            dy: fromFrame.size.height * offset.dy)
        toView.frame = toFrame

        }, completion: {finshed in
            let wasCancelled = transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled
            // When we complete, tell the transition context
            // passing along the BOOL that indicates whether the transition
            // finished or not.
            transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toView)
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!wasCancelled)
    })
}
```

Below is the screen shot
[image]

Comment: Do you have only black screen?

Comment: Added screenshot please check once.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBattula Is your storyboard pattern like: Tab bar controller -> Navigation controller -> View controller?

Comment: @Amanpreet yes using  Tab bar controller -> Navigation controller -> View controller this pattern.

Comment: It should be root view controller the view after navigation controller. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems Like you have taken `UINavigationController` for your second tab. But somehow your connection from `UINavigationController` to your **secondViewController** is lost. Please check the image of a storyboard which may be in your scenario.[image: the image of a storyboard]

Comment: Actually this is not the scenario. If possible can you please check sample codes, which i mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same as a blank screen and I fixed it by making the current view it the initial view controller.

> check is Initial View Controller
> [image]